# How to scroll elements to make space for expanding element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got the following div hierarchy in my page!

```
<div id="bill-list">
    <div id="bill-panel">
    <!-- Bill -->
         <div class="bill">
         <!-- Bill description - Holds Bill details -->
         <div class="bill-description">
            <div class="bill-info bill-number"><span>000A</span></div>
            <div class="bill-info table-name"><span>TABLE 78</span></div>
            <div class="bill-info room-number"><span>A678</span></div>
                            <div class="bill-info amount"><span>76.00 USD</span></div>
            <div class="bill-remove-icon"></div>
         </div>

         <!-- Bill Item list -->
         <div class="bill-item-list">

         <!-- Item : This is a sample element & will be cleared when system loads -->
         <div class="bill-item">

            <!-- Item image -->
            <div class="bill-item-img"></div>
            <!-- Item description -->
            <div class="bill-item-description">
            <div class="bill-item-name">

            <!-- Item Name -->
            <p class="bill-item-name-left">Normal Cofee</p>
            <!-- Item Price -->
            <p class="bill-item-name-right">170.00</p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Total item price -->
        <div class="bill-item-price">
        <span>170.00 USD</span>
        </div>

        <!-- Item Quantity -->
        <div class="bill-item-amount">
        <span>1</span>
    </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Increas & Decrease item Quantity -->
    <div class="bill-amount-selection">
    <a class="amount-increase" href="#"></a>
    <a class="amount-decrease" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Remove bill link -->
    <div class="item-drop-point"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>                      

</div>
```

I'm designing a web application where I load the bills and create each bill using jQuery. So I create each element of bill and append them to the bill panel! I've enabled scrolling of the bill list using the following code. I've used dragscroller as the scrolling plugin.

```
$('#bill-list').dragscrollable({dragSelector: '#bill-panel', acceptPropagatedEvent: true});
```

And the bill has a click event of it's own where I expand the bill using jQuery slide toggle.

```
$(document).on('click',".bill-description",function()
{
    //close all bills 
    $(".bill-item-list").not($(this).next(".bill-item-list")).slideUp(600);
    //open the clicked bills
    $(this).next(".bill-item-list").slideToggle(600);

});
```

The above code closes any other element that is open and expand the clicked bill. Following is the CSS used for the elements.

```
#bill-list {
  max-height: 581px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
  #bill-panel {
  max-height: 575px;
}
.bill {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.bill-description {
    height: 30px;
    font-family: MyriadProReg;
    background-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

All these effects work fine. The problem is when I expand an element that is in the bottom of the bill panel, it gets expanded, but I have to manually scroll to view the expanded section. I've go no idea on how to fix it!

What I need is a help to do the following. There is a list of bills that can be scrolled. Each bill has around 5 bill items. and when I expand an element at the bottom of the bill panel, bills should auto scroll to show the expanded bill.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the jQuery scrollTo() plugin? It may be helpful in this case. Info and download [here](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html).

Comment: I tried that but no use! it doesn't get scrolled to the expanding element.

Comment: You have to tell it what position to scroll to, so you will need to do a little calculation to find out the top of the element to scroll to. Try using the jQuery method .offset() for this. http://api.jquery.com/offset/